# Create React App Allow Access Control Origin Issue

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, same-origin-policy

I deployed a weather app created with create-react-app. In development I would use  the chrome extension allow access control origin. Now that it is deployed with github pages, I'm getting the error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://boka44.github.io' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

It seems like I need to add a header to my server, but I'm confused as to how and where to add it.

My code is here: https://github.com/Boka44/weather

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The API endpoint (The one that provides weather information) which you are calling has disabled CORS which means you can never make a client-facing call (i.e. through a browser) because the browser will block the call.

You have 2 options here:

- **If you can change the API endpoint**: you can add a CORS header to allow origins from your client app's domain.
- **If you cannot change the server code**: Create your own API endpoint that calls the original API endpoint and have your client app call your own API. (i.e. You just make a proxy server that directs your calls to the original API endpoint). In this case, you can specify a CORS header on your server to allow calls from your client app domain only.

Comment: That's where part of my issue lies. I'm not how to do either of those. I added a proxy server to my package.json but not sure how to set it up. Also unsure on where or how to add the CORS header. Bit of a noob on this one and I can't find good documentation on it.

Comment: You need to create a server, you can use Azure, AWS or GCP they all provide free tiers. Just create a nodejs server that calls the API end point. In your client app, you will call the server you just created. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-app for a tutorial on creating a simple nodejs server on Azure

Answer (score 0):

[Dark Sky API docs](https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq#cross-origin) says that it is not allowing CORS. So you can't get data to your client side code from their server. So create a [proxy server](http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/examples/simple/) in PHP or some other platforms, which will make an api call and produces the JSON formatted response.